# TypeError: DriveApp.getFolderByID is not a function and TypeError: DriveApp.getFileByID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, typeerror

So I have a very simple bit of code at the very top of my script that says

`let files2 = DriveApp.getFolderByID(reports_folder)`

However, when I try to run this, it gives me

> TypeError: DriveApp.getFolderByID is not a function

and the same

> TypeError: DriveApp.getFileByID is not a function

when I try that. Any ideas?

Comment: How about modifying `getFolderByID` to `getFolderById`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)

Comment: I stared at your answer for a SOLID 5 minutes trying to figure out what the difference even was between your two typed things. This indeed did fix my issues, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.